How to fix DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true?
I am using rome tool link to parse the feed, When I parse the certain feeds I am getting below doctype error.
// Sample code
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndImage;
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader;
 

@Override
            public List<?> handleResponse(ClassicHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
                    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    List<SyndEntry> recentEntries = filterRecentEntries(feed);
}

// Error
[Test worker] ERROR com.rss.rome.RomeClient - feed url https://razzball.com/feed/ failed Invalid XML: Error on line 1: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true. 

